# Cannot resolve Symbol Context in import android.content.Context

Tags: android, android-studio

import android.content.Context; Context appears in red. And on placing my mouse over it the error is Cannot resolve Symbol Context. It was working before but now something happened.

Comment: Try Invalidate caches and Restart. It may solve the issue.

Comment: Yeah it was all due to the use of callback generator invalidate cache solved the problem thanks